# Odd graphical bug: a copy of component A is painted on component B. HELP! (java)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I have made a simple paint program in which you can use a brush-tool to paint some different colors and erase (simply paint in white).

It works fine, but I have a very strange graphical bug which causes the toolpanel and the last mouseovered color/tool-icon to be painted on top of the drawpanel.

Implementation: The frame holds two extentions of JPanel: a ToolPanel and a DrawPanel. ToolPanel holds two JPanels which hold the color- and toolbuttons. The Buttons are extensions of JComponent.

link to screenshot (I'm not allowed to post images appearently):

[image]

note: The buttons in the second "fake" toolpanel are not actual buttons that can be clicked and I can paint on top of it. If I paint on the "fake" color button in the left corner it will be repainted again when I mouseover a new color and enter the drawpanel with the mouse.

note 2: I used to have a JMenuBar which was also painted in the drawpanel. It was repainted each time the drawpanel is mouseovered after the window (not just the panel) lost focus once.

Some code:
(I know the tool selection implementation isn't the best :P)

DrawPanel's paintComponent method:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    if(isMousePressed) {
        if(tool == "BRUSH") {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(currentEvent.getX(), currentEvent.getY(), 30, 30);
        } else if(tool == "ERASER") {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillOval(currentEvent.getX(), currentEvent.getY(), 30, 30);

        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is any relevant information or code that I left out.

Hypothesis:
I didn't call super.paintComponent in DrawPanels paintComponent-method, maybe that causes some problems? The reason that I didn't is that if I do, it will repaint the background all the time so only the dot I painted last will be visible. Not sure if the supercall actually solves the problem or if the fake-panel is just covered by the background as well. Maybe I need to work around that some other way? Or is it something else?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 For the "WTF" screenshot. :D

Comment: Don't use "==" to compare Strings. Use the equals(...) method.

Comment: Did you ever fix this or could you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're probably altering the Graphics object instead of creating new ones (`g.create()`) and therefore doing stuff like setting bounds or clip regions that might alter paint positions.

If you can post a bit more detail (such as all the places you paint) or even a full [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html), then I will update this answer to be more specific.  Until then, that's impossible.

It is good practise to always create a new `Graphics` object to work with.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (isMousePressed) {
        // create the new Graphics context which
        // we can work with/modify independently
        g2 = g.create();
        // use "str".equals() for String comparisons
        if ("BRUSH".equals(tool)) {
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fillOval(currentEvent.getX(), currentEvent.getY(), 30, 30);
        } else if ("ERASER".equals(tool)) {
            g2.setColor(getBackground());
            g2.fillOval(currentEvent.getX(), currentEvent.getY(), 30, 30);
        }
        // you should always dispose() of a Graphics
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for "disporing" your Graphics2D copy. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have updated the paintComponent method according to your comments except for the super call because if I do only the last dot I painted will be visible (and even that one disappears if the DrawPanel loses focus).
edit: posted before I was finished >.<
Creating new Graphics objects didn't seem to help in this case though. The only objects I paint except for the DrawPanel are the buttons.

Comment: Also I don't mess with clips anywhere. When I paint the buttons I just basically paint a rectangle or an icon and make it a little different if it's mouseovered/pressed.

Comment: We'll need more from you then @tobes i.e. a full working example.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I worked with Swing but your basic problem is the fact the background is not being repainted.  This does mean a proper working component should paint the entire area every single time, so you will have to save and repaint any previous drawing.

You could try setting your component to transparent (check for a setTransparent or setOpaque method) but as it's been several years I'm not sure what the exact result will be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have considered something like that as well (repainting the drawing all the time). Do you know how that could be implemented?

Comment: Just call [`fillRect`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) before you do anything else (i.e. the topmost component).

Comment: 1. Follow Charles' advice.
2. When a component paints it needs to paint all of itself.  So if you want to hold on to the users previous paintings you're going to have to store it in memory somehow so you can reproduce it.  One way would be to store everything they've done and go through each step every time, but that could become very cumbersome.  Another approach might be to store it as an image in memory and paint it every time before adding the user edit.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what you can do.  Do all your painting to an image and then draw the image on the graphics.